# Solr: how to add unicode character to synonyms?

Tags: solr

Right now I have this in my synonyms.txt file, which didn't work:

```
\u00be, three-quarter, three quarter
```

I also tried:

```
\\u00be, three-quarter, three quarter
```

As well as:

```
"\u00be", three-quarter, three quarter
```

Which didn't work either. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't think the synonyms.txt-file supports unicode code points as used in string escapes. How about just entering the unicode character?

Comment: @MatsLindh I tried that too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the character into the synonym.txt file.

Re-opened the file in notepad and saved it with UTF-8 encoding.

This would take the character as expected and there is no need to go with unicode code.